# After uploading build to S3, elements are invisible but picked up by inspector?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I recently uploaded a build file to my `S3 bucket`. All files were uploaded, but on the actual site, `only the background image shows.`

All elements and code are picked up by the inspector, but are invisible.

I should also note that the elements are functional. The buttons still work as intended. Just invisible.

If it will help, my site's URL is `www.sidemountcalc.com`

Any ideas?

Comment: If you look at the `.calculator` element in the CSS inspector, you'll notice that its opacity is set to `1%`. There may be something wonky with your source maps, since I'm unable to find the line that sets that. If you check locally and can't find that `opacity: 1%` line, try clearing your build cache and rebuilding/reuploading fresh.

Comment: @superhawk610 Thank you! I will do some digging and try this out!

Comment: @superhawk610 thanks to you I found the answer on a previous SO post. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here:

[The opacity value was changed to 1% after building the Reacjs project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58853844/the-opacity-value-was-changed-to-1-after-building-the-reacjs-project)

In short, issue with react and opacity. Opacity is set from 0.0 - 1.0. So 75% opacity needs to be 0.75.